# Fermat's Little Theorem Problem with an exponent of an exponent

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you solve this?

$$2^{5^{2017}} \bmod 11$$

I tried my own method, and I got that:

$$2^{5^{2017}} \equiv 10\pmod{11}$$

But I'm not sure it's the correct answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your method and explain why you are unsure about it.

Comment: First, I applied FLT to 5^(2017) mod 11, and got that 78125 ≡ 1(mod 11). Second, I applied FLT to 2^(78125) mod 11, and finally got that the whole thing 2^(5^2017)) ≡ 1 (mod 11)

Comment: Use the linked mod order reduction method to reduce the expt $\bmod 10,\,$ using $$\large  5^{\large 1+n}\bmod  10 = 5(5^{\large n}\bmod 2) = 5(1^{\large n}\bmod 2) = 5(1)\ \ {\rm for}\,\ n\ge 0$$ by the [mod distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $11$ is a prime, $2^{10}\overset{11}{\equiv}1$ Hence because $5^{2017}\overset{10}{\equiv}5$, we have $2^{5^{2017}}\overset{11}{\equiv}2^5\overset{11}{\equiv}10$ and you are right!